# opening video in new activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the main activity in android to another activity and playing a video in the new activity. but, even I changed in the manifest the main activity, it didn't show me the video when I'm starting the app. I tried to Check in the Logcat if the activity is still launched, and i didn't see any message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mta2223">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MTA2223">
        <activity
            android:name=".Entering"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityShowingPlayers"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The new activity

```
package com.example.mta2223;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Entering extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entering);
         videoView= (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoV);
         videoView.setVideoPath("res/raw/intrologo.3gp");
         videoView.start();

       while (videoView.isPlaying()){
           Log.d("HEy","hey");
       }
       videoView.stopPlayback();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> In this code get video path from raw folder

```
String path = "android.resource://com.example.mta2223" + "/" + R.raw.intrologo;
videoView.setVideoPath(path);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: The first one to put on the original Main activity?

Comment: Edited on my code please check

Comment: The new activity had been launched ( I know it by Logging) but after that the app dead

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoPath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: your videopath get method in wrong

Comment: Edited on my code please check